# MAC pip install kulka error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

Tags: python, git, macos, gcc, pip

I have been trying to install `pip install kulka` for a long time now. I keep running into this same issue. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling. I have also tried just about everything I can find on other threads.

Another thread told me to try doing `brew install cmake` and that also failed.

```
WL-198-2:anaconda aschantz$ brew install cmake
Updating Homebrew...
xcodebuild: error: SDK "/path/to/Mac10.11SDK" cannot be located.
git: error: unable to find utility "git", not a developer tool or in PATH
Error: Failure while executing: git config --local --replace-all homebrew.private true
```

I'll be super grateful for any help!!

```
//System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSXPCConnection.h:185:1: error: unknown type name ‘nullable’
 - (nullable NSXPCInterface *)interfaceForSelector:(SEL)sel argumentIndex:(NSUInteger)arg ofReply:(BOOL)ofReply;
 ^
//System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSXPCConnection.h:185:13: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘NSXPCInterface’
 - (nullable NSXPCInterface *)interfaceForSelector:(SEL)sel argumentIndex:(NSUInteger)arg ofReply:(BOOL)ofReply;
             ^
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

---

> Command "//anaconda/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/j9/_j_fqs0x1hs_jy0bsmkx4jz00000gn/T/pip-build-jsu4tnbk/pyobjc-framework-Cocoa/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/j9/_j_fqs0x1hs_jy0bsmkx4jz00000gn/T/pip-snryv41w-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/j9/_j_fqs0x1hs_jy0bsmkx4jz00000gn/T/pip-build-jsu4tnbk/pyobjc-framework-Cocoa/

Comment: Do you have gcc installed? It's not there by default unless you install Xcode.

Comment: Same goes for `git`. It looks like you may not have the Xcode command line tools installed. Try running `xcode-select --install`

Comment: @robertklep I believe I have xcode installed.  I definitely have git  as I use it regularly. I can run apps through xcode and when I try that command I get this.  `WL-198-2:anaconda aschantz$ xcode-select --install
xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates`

Comment: @Abby weird, the first error states that `git` can't be found in `$PATH`

Comment: @Abby does installing anything else via pip work? It could be an error in this module's code...